# Get JSON output from PHP alogn with PHP output (like print(), etc.)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am building a PHP application. I need to do an ajax call to a PHP script which rertuns HTML code. However, I also need to receive a variable along with the PHP output. I have tried to achieve this with JSON, however I get either PHP output or just the JSON data. When I use dataType: 'json' in my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'script.php',
   method: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json'
   success: function(returnData){
      $('body').append(returnData);
      alert(returnData.num);
   }
});
```

I am unable to get the output from 'echo' in the PHP script:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
echo json_encode(array('num' => 11));
?>
```

So, what I need in the jQuery ajax call is to receive 'Hello World' as PHP output and append it to body and then get the 'num' variable from JSON. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: when you send json for ajax, you can't send anything else. In other words, there should be only one `echo` in your code

Answer (score 0):

in PHP

> echo json_encode(array('num' => 11, 'text' => 'Hello World'));

in ajax:

```
   success: function(returnData){
      $('body').append(returnData.text);
      alert(returnData.num);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse both at once - your best option would be to include the HTML output as part of the JSON output. Here's an example:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('num' => 11, 'html' => 'Hello World!'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Echoing anything other then JSON will break your JSON, you should put any expected output/data inside your JSON.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = array(
    'hello' => 'Hello World', 
    'num' => 11
);

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Then in your jquery,

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'script.php',
   method: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json'
   success: function(returnData){
        //your hello world string
        $('body').append(returnData.hello);
        //your num
        alert(returnData.num);
   }
});
```

Comment: That partly solves my problem: what if I need to output the whole PHP script and not just one string. Is it possible using PHP ob_start() and ob_end_flush?

Comment: Dont mix your tools, ob_start() is a way but you might as well just use `dataType: 'html'` instead.